# pandas apply function over columns of dataframe with if/truth statements

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I have three columns in a pandas dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'month':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12],
                   'day':[10,23,16,30,1,23,3,28,29,1,4,2],
                    'year':[1990,1990,1990,1990,1990,1990,1990,1990,1990,1990,1990,1990]})
```

I want to return the water year in another column which is defined as year +1 for any day after September 28.  For example September 29 1990 is water year 1991.

I have a function that works on its own

```
def wy(month, day, year):
    if month >8 and day > 28:
        year = year + 1
    else:
        if month>9:
            year = year + 1
        else:
            year = year
    return year
wy(9,30,2000)
```

But

```
df['wy'] = wy(df['month'],df['day'],df['year'])
```

returns the error

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

When I tried to apply it to the dataframe.  I have looked at the docs and other questions and have tried multiple other functions such as

```
def wy(month, day, year):
    if any(month >8 & day > 28):
        year = year + 1
    else:
        if any(month>9):
            year = year + 1
        else:
            year = year
    return year


def wy(month, day, year):
    if any((month >8 & day > 28)|month>9):
        year = year + 1
    return year
```

But I still am returning errors.  I have also tried a lambda expression (not very pretty)

```
df['wy'] = (lambda x,y,z:z+1 if (x >8 & y > 28)|y>9 else z, df['month'],df['day'],df['year'])
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a tuple of `(month, day)` and compare to that applied across the column axis, eg:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'month':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12],
                   'day':[10,23,16,30,1,23,3,28,29,1,4,2],
                    'year':[1990,1990,1990,1990,1990,1990,1990,1990,1990,1990,1990,1990]})
```

Using:

```
df.apply(lambda L: L.year + ((L.month, L.day) >= (9, 28)), axis=1)
```

Gives you:

```
0     1990
1     1990
2     1990
3     1990
4     1990
5     1990
6     1990
7     1990
8     1991
9     1991
10    1991
11    1991
dtype: int64
```

This works because tuples are compared element by element and month/day are natural ordering. Any true condition evaluates to what's effectively `1` and a false condition to `0` - and we add that to the year to move it into the next if required.

Comment: this works and taught me something valuable about tuples

Comment: @JeffTilton oh - probably want `>` instead of `>=` but you've probably already noticed that :)